# Continuous deployment from Visual Studio Team Services to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to automatically deploy from Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) after a successful build a C# program to an azure app service without success.

I can only do it to a cloud service (classic) rather app service.

[image]
[image]

I've seen that I could plug Team Services directly to the app service with "deployment source" (I did tried so far because both tenant, Team Services & Azure one are different and requires some effort)
[image]

but wouldn't it break the normal release / test process from Team Services?
I can only find little information over internet regarding these topics ...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What error do you have when try with "Azure Website Deployment"? It is used to deploy Azure Web App.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I already succeed to deploy in an Azure Web App, but I want to deploy to an App Service rather Azure Web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also add a [FTP Upload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/ftp-upload) task in your build definition to publish the output to Azure App Service via [FTP Method](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#overview).

Comment: worked like a charm. but I hope a new "deployment task" will be created one day preventing numerous "ftp endpoints" and old school deployment.

Answer (score 0):

To publish to an Azure App Service, you need to use either of the following Agent tasks:

[image: Deployment Options]

Here is a walkthrough: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnet4-to-azure

When making a new build definition, it is easiest to choose the Deployment -> Azure WebApp option.

Comment: I have Azure webapp option in builds scope, but not in releases one. Only Azure Cloud Service Deployment, Azure Service Fabric Deployment and Azure Website Deployment. Tried all of them without success.

Comment: All of the agent tasks that are available in build definitions should also be in release manager. If that is not the case for you, I would try an in private browsing session to rule out a cache issue. If it still isn't there, I would open a support ticket.

Comment: Using the "deployment source" option in Azure portal will directly clone the code into Azure whenever you push to your VSTS repo. That code would then get compiled and deployed to Azure app service directly.

For more control on your flow, use the build and release definitions in VSTS to set that up. It is strange that you do not have "Azure Web App Deployment task" in Release. If that is the case, please send us an email with your VSTS account info and we will take a look (rm_customer_queries _at_ microsoft _dot_ com). What error do you get when use the Azure website deployment task?

Comment: Also, is your build definition copying the proper ZIP file for the release definition to use when publishing? Or are you running a build from release manager?

Comment: @VijayMachiraju I've mixed up templates & tasks ... I can find Azure Web App Deployment on Build & Release tab. But it's not clear for me if I have no choice to use a Azure Web App Deployment which can (only ?) points to a classic Cloud Service linked with a storage account or is there a way to deploy to a new flavoured App Service. Or if currently there is no "click & play" way and have to try with powershell ?